# Add custom post related by custom field to custom post

Tags: custom-post-types, advanced-custom-fields, pods-framework

I hope to be able to explain my question.

My scenario is the following.

I have *events* post type created by a plugin for exhibition in a theatre season.

I want to have at the bottom of every single event a short bio of author(s), actor(s), ... who have to be all in the same set as sometime actors are also director and viceversa.

I created by Pods a Custom Post Type *people* where I store bio, short bio, featured image and events (linked to events post)

I created by Advanced Custom Field three Custom Fields: *director*, *author* and *actor* as relation with *people*.

While I was able to create by pod template the post, for people in my "people template" I couldn't.

In my event I often have more people for the same position.

By php snippet I could dump the multidimensional array of the director and i had my value, but after that I couldn't go on.

Is there any plugin to do this.
Or there is any code workaround?

Comment: It sounds like director/actor/author is a "category" (aka taxonomy) classifying a Person. So instead of using ACF for the director/author/actor stuff, I'd create a custom Taxonomy (in Pods, since you're already using it).  Once you have that set up you can turn to the Pods documentation for how to display the content via templates / shortcodes.

Comment: No, because it's not a defined classification.
Many people for an exhibition are director and for many others are actors.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. I think I'd still set up director/actor etc as a "Role" taxonomy. Then I'd create a 'Repeater' field containing two child fields: Taxonomy (Role) and Relationship (connected to the Person CPT). The Repeater would appear when editing Events, allowing you to choose multiple People + Roles for the current Event. (Using a Taxonomy instead of custom field means it's possible to add roles and edit previous roles easily - with a field you run into backwards-compatibility issues if you try to do that). I'm not familiar with Pods but I know you could do this with ACF Pro if Pods can't do it

Comment: This looks great. Thanks for the suggestion. I'll try.
I'm at first experience with a so deep use of ACF, custom fields and pods, so I loved you.
Really thank you.
I'll let you know here.

Comment: I followed your way. With ACF pro I guess (LOL) I created all the backend structure. But now I need to put all those stuffs in frontend by shortcode, widget or by php snippet, but I don't prefer this way.

Comment: Yeah the display stuff is another whole thing. :) ACF has a lot of documentation on their site that will help with the code, but how you insert it on the Events CPT really depends on the plugin you're using for that.

Comment: As I'm not so confident with coding a colleague helped me writing a shortcode function that I placed where needed.